# Recommendations - Scheduling software/components .Net

Tags: .net, scheduling

I'm starting a new back office scheduling app for a doctor's office.  .Net 3.5.  I'm trying to save time and money.  Can anyone recommend a suite of tools (Infragistics, etc) that are best of breed for a scheduling application?  More advanced than that, if anyone has a codebase they are willing to share or sell the base of, I would be interested in talking...

Answer (score 1):

I've used [DayPilot](http://www.daypilot.org/) Pro in the past - and it did a decent job.  I think we had originally started out with the Lite version - but at some point needed to upgrade to the Pro version to pick up a feature that we needed.

It's not as pretty as some of the other scheduling controls (Infragistics, Telerik, etc) - but it did the job well enough for the price.  If given another project that did scheduling, I wouldn't have a problem using this again.

Answer (score 0):

If they already are running SharePoint or Exchange 2007, that might be a good place to start. Especially the Exchange angle.